# Custom AuthorizeAttribute Failing to Authorize

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, authorization

I am unable to make my custom authorization attribute return anything but a 401 unauthorized on controller methods.

I've setup a very basic Custom Authorization Attribute:

```
 public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters) {
        filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
        filters.Add(new AuthorizeAttribute());
        filters.Add(new CustomAuthorizationAttribute());  //<---Custom 
    }
```

The class itself:

```
public class CustomAuthorizationAttribute : System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        return true;
    }

    protected override HttpValidationStatus OnCacheAuthorization(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        return base.OnCacheAuthorization(httpContext);
    }

    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
    }


    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
    }

}
```

I've decorated my controller's actions with the CustomAuthorizationAttribute:

```
  [HttpPost]
    [CustomAuthorization]
    public ActionResult UploadFile(FormCollection fileUpload)
    {...
```

Obviously I must be missing something simple because this code always results in a 401 unauthorized response.

The AuthorizeCore method breakpoint does not get hit, but occasionally OnAuthorization method does.

I'm new to MVC5. What am I missing? How do I make this authorization work based on my custom criteria?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There appears to be a triple redundancy with your authorize attributes. You've added three authorize filters to a single controller action. Two here:

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters) {
        filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
        filters.Add(new AuthorizeAttribute());
        filters.Add(new CustomAuthorizationAttribute());  //<---Custom 
    }
```

... and one here:

```
  [HttpPost]
    [CustomAuthorization]
    public ActionResult UploadFile(FormCollection fileUpload)
```

I'm guessing that the first AuthorizeAttribute (vanilla) is applied first, hits its own AuthorizeCore(), returns false and sends your context onto 401-ville.

Try removing both global filter registrations, then see if the controller action behaves as you expect.

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters) {
            filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
        }
```